# Will Marvel's next film include Iron Man and the X-Men together?

Tags: marvel, x-men, iron-man

At the end of the movie *The Wolverine*, when Logan was about to enter a security metal detector, there was an ad on the TV screen which shows “TRASK” industries.

That’s an anagram of “STARK” industries.

Are there any plans for Marvel to produce a movie with both Iron Man and the X-Men? If so, when will it be ready and screened?

Comment: The ending of "The Wolverine" was alluding to "X men: Days of future past". Will have to check about the STARK reference.

Comment: Almost certainly not, since Marvel can't use mutants in the cinematic universe - AFAIK, Fox still owns the rights to use them

Comment: Trask Industries is from the X-Men universe. http://www.trask-industries.com/#/home

Comment: Not exactly a dupe of any of these, but very much related: [Why is no mutant from X-men series a member of S.H.I.E.L.D?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42876/5184), [Spiderman not in Avengers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17904/5184), [Is The Amazing Spider-Man part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16551/5184), [Which other movies are “in canon” with The Wolverine?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39968/5184)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there's not going to be an Iron Man and X-Men film any time soon.

Bolivar Trask, and his creation, the Sentinels, are a long-running part of the X-Men corner of the Marvel universe. They're introducing him and his company Trask Industries in the next X-Men film, with that company building Sentinels, which are a major part of the film's story. There's no relationship between Trask and Stark.

Marvel cannot and will not be making a film that contains both Iron Man and the X-Men. Years ago, Marvel licensed the Mutants portion of their universe to Fox. Since then, Fox has been making a steady stream of X-Men films.

With the release of the first *Iron Man* film, Marvel started making their own films. Since then, they've built up the Marvel Cinematic Universe that's comprised of the *Iron Man*, *Hulk*, *Thor*, *Captain America*, and *Avengers* films, along with *Marvel's Agents of SHIELD* and various DVD extra shorts. These films, shorts, and TV series are all made and owned by Marvel, and share a universe.  All the X-Men films mentioned above share a separate Fox-owned universe. Marvel has their superhero sandbox, Fox has their own separate one, and they have little reason to combine them, since both of them have been successful on their own.

Also see [my answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/14932/209) to a related question over on Movies & TV.SE. Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch are one special exception to the above due to the specifics of Fox's license.

Now, this license will at some point come to an end, but that's likely 5+ years out, since it would require it to be no longer profitable for Fox to keep making X-Men films. So if several X-Men films in a row bomb at the box office, then maybe we'll see this happen. But if the X-Men movies start doing that poorly, chances are Marvel's own films aren't doing well too due to the similarity of genre/subject matter, so who knows what would happen at that point.

Comment: [But if the X-Men movies start doing that poorly, chances are Marvel's own films aren't doing well too due to the similarity of genre/subject matter, so who knows what would happen at that point.]

…erm… Actually this part of your answer doesn't make that much of a sense.

The "Superhero genre", just like any genre, depends as much on execution, as it does on genre-specific elements and their "popularity".

Eg. The Superman franchise had a successful bout in the 80s, just as the campy Batman TV series was successful in the 60s. [cont]

Comment: When Tim Burton (re)launched the successful Batman movie franchise in 89, most people were convinced the cinematised/televised "Superhero" genre was dead.

As in the difference of execution between Marvel, X-Men & DC "extended" cinematic/TV universes, in film and TV, and the mixed/criticised results of all three, a downfall of one franchise due to poor execution or tone mismatch ("what people want/need/like" Vs. "What people get"), doesn't mean other approaches would be less effective or successful. [cont]

Comment: Eg: Relaunching the (quite naive-feeling) Christopher Reeve's Superman today might bomb, while a stripped-down ambitious Joaquin Phoenix "Joker" struck the right note.

Moreover, the "Superhero genre" is less rigid in tone, story beats and visual language than the more "rigidly defined" (but no less creative/artistically worthy) "Noir Genre". Through these last decades of "Comics Medium" self-awareness, it has already spawned extremely diverse treatments of the matter, in wildly varying styles, and degrees of depth/seriousness. [cont]

Comment: It has become something of a Mythology  on which to project Human Experience (comparable to the role of Greco-Roman myth in the classical arts). With one added benefit: artists can create new myths ("breaking canon") without needing to defend their choice to do so. 

Nobody could foresee "Watchmen" (or any other deconstruction of the superhero genre, like eg "The Brat Pack", "The Boys", or even "Multiversity"), to spawn the "Watchmen" TV series of 2019/2020, with its ambitious deconstruction of race relations in America. [End]

Answer (score 4):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/list/mjEOeFw9MMI/), the next two Marvel movies are both sequels; "Captain America: The Winter Soldier" and "The Avengers: Age of Ultron"

Captain America has a cast listing for "[The Falcon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_%28comics%29#Powers.2C_abilities.2C_and_equipment)" and The Avengers has a cast listing for "[Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28comics%29)" both of whom are mutants from the X-Men comic book canon.

Comment: Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch *are* mutants in the comics, but Marvel cannot identify them as such within their own movies due to legal rights currently owned by Fox.

Comment: Also, it is true that it was theorized that Falcon was a mutant at one point in the comics, but that was later [debunked](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2011/12/10/the-abandoned-an-forsaked-the-falcon-is-a-mutant/).

Comment: You missed _Guardians of the Galaxy_, and _Ant-Man_ has been announced to be the 4th next one - [Wikipedia is a bit better at release dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Films)